# Optimal conditional density choice

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control, calculus-of-variations

Suppose $X$ is a random variable whose density is denoted by $p(x)$. We can observe a realization of $X$ and we want to take an action $Y$ to minimize

$$E[(Y-X)^{2}]$$

What is the optimal choice of the conditional density $q(y|x)$ of $Y|X$ Formally:

$$\min_{q}\{E[(Y-X)^{2}]=\int(y-x)^{2}q(y|x)p(x)dydx\}$$

such that

$$(\forall x) \int q(y|x)dy=1 \quad (1)$$

$$-E[E[\log_{2}q(Y|X)|X]]-\{-E[\log_{2}(\int q(Y|x)p(x)dx)]\} \leq C \quad (2)$$
where
$$-\int E[\log_{2}q(Y|X)|X]p(x)dx=-\int\int(\int q(y|x)p(x)dx)p(x)\log_{2}q(y|x)dxdy$$
$$-E[\log_{2}(\int q(Y|x)p(x)dx)]=\int(\int q(y|x)p(x)dx)\log_{2}(\int q(y|x)p(x)dx)dy$$

The intuition of the last constraint is based on information-theoretic entropy. Before observing $X$, the entropy of $(X,Y)$ is defined as:

$$-E[\log_{2}(\int q(Y|x)p(x)dx)]$$

After observing $X=x$, the entropy is:

$$-E[\log_{2}q(Y|X)|X=x]$$

So the reduction in the entropy is:

$$-E[\log_{2}q(Y|X)|X=x]-\{-E[\log_{2}(\int q(Y|x)p(x)dx)]\}$$

The average reduction in the entropy is:

$$-E[E[\log_{2}q(Y|X)|X]]-\{-E[\log_{2}(\int q(Y|x)p(x)dx)]\}$$

Then there is an upper bound of the entropy reduction:

$$-E[E[\log_{2}q(Y|X)|X]]-\{-E[\log_{2}(\int q(Y|x)p(x)dx)]\} \leq C$$

The trivial case is $C=\infty$

For simplification, let
$$h(y)=\int q(y|x)p(x)dx$$
represent the density of $Y$, then above constraint (2) can be translated as:
$$-\int\int h(y)p(x)\log_{2}q(y|x)dxdy-[-\int h(y)\log_{2}h(y)dy]\leq C \quad (2*)$$

#### The question is:

When $X$ distribution is Gaussian, what is the optimal $q(y|x)$ given the constraint (1) and (2*)?

A natural guess is that $q(y|x)$ is also Gaussian, how to show it?

Comment: why not just identify $Y$ and $X$, so joint distribution $P(x,y)=p(x)\delta(x-y)$ and $q(y|x)=\delta(y-x)$; that would give you $E[(Y-X)^2]=0$, and you can't do better than that...

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker, it seems that this construction can not satisfy last constraint except for the extreme case where C is infinite, how to deal with the constraint is the difficult and non-trivial point.

Comment: I find it hard to read expressions like $E[\log_2q(Y|X)|X]$.  Can you restate the problem in pure integral terms, without any reference to conditionality?  E.g.:  given $p(x)$, find $q(x,y)$ which minimizes $\int (x-y)^2 q(x,y) dx dy$ subject to $\int q(x,y)dy = p(x)$ and ... what?

Comment: @MattF.  I add a constraint (2*) and (2*) is an equivalent translation from (2) and the expectation operator is represented by the integral sign.